# ASP.NET Custom Control Adapter not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am trying to write a simple ControlAdapter below is a very simplified case, but I still can't seem to get it to work. In my simplified case I just want to write something out before my control is rendered.

I defined my control adapter as such:

```
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.Adapters;

namespace Test.Web.Common.Controls.ControlAdapters {

  public class RadioBtnStyleAdapter : WebControlAdapter {


    protected override void BeginRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {

      writer.WriteLine("<!--- CONTROL ADAPTER -->");
      writer.WriteLine("<div><b>TEST</b></div");

      base.BeginRender(writer);
    }
  }
}
```

- I then added an App_Browsers folder under my Test.Web project.
- I then added a default.browser file under App_Browsers

And my default.browsers looks like

```
<browsers>
  <browser id="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton" adapterType="Test.Web.Common.Controls.ControlAdapters.RadioBtnStyleAdapter"></adapter>
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```

It is my understanding that should be enough, and the framework should pick up the the adapter, however it never actually seems to fire.

Any suggestions about what I could be missing?

**Update**

I am able get it to work if I programmaticaly add the adapter on Page_Init like so

```
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Adapters["System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton"] = "Test.Web.Common.Controls.ControlAdapters.RadioBtnStyleAdapter";
```

But nothing I have read show this as a required step, so I am not convinced this is correct.

Comment: Did you ever got this to work based on the marked answer? I am unable to get this to work with all the permutations - refID does not work, nor the programmatic approach above that worked for you.

Comment: I did, but I needed some additional information which I received from my follow up question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33556746/render-control-in-controladapter

The gist of it was to inherit from ControlAdapter  vs WebControlAdapter

Comment: Thanks. The problem i was facing was i was not getting the override suggestion in the intellisense. I then overrode the render method and it started y to work. I will post the working code should it help someone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change the id attribute of the browser element to **refID** as follows.
The id attribute is used if you would like to give it a unique name, when mapping/identifying a particular browser, and refID is used when associating new capabilities (such as Control Adapters) with an existing browser definition. And that's exactly what you want to do.

```
<browsers>
  <browser refID="Default">
    <controlAdapters>
      <adapter controlType="System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton" adapterType="Test.Web.Common.Controls.ControlAdapters.RadioBtnStyleAdapter"></adapter>
    </controlAdapters>
  </browser>
</browsers>
```