# Render Control in ControlAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

This is some what related to my [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33551179/asp-net-custom-control-adapter-not-firing) posted, but not exactly. I finally was able to get my control adapter to fire, however I cannot get it to work as I expected.

The whole reason I would like to use a control adapter is to add additional markup to system controls such as a RadioButton. I am using another framework that that expect this.

If we assume a RadioButton without any changes would render like

```
<input id="MainContent_RadioButton1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButton1" value="RadioButton1" /><label for="MainContent_RadioButton1">My Radio Button</label>
```

I would like to change the markup to look like

```
<div class="wrapper">
<input id="MainContent_RadioButton1" type="radio" name="ctl00$MainContent$RadioButton1" value="RadioButton1" /><label for="MainContent_RadioButton1">My Radio Button</label>
</div>
```

This is a really simplified example, so I am not looking for suggestions of sub classing my controls, or adding a panel to my page with a class.

In my Page-Init I have

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Adapters["System.Web.UI.WebControls.RadioButton"] =
    "ControlAdapterTest.Controls.ControlAdaptors.RadioButtonAdapter";
}
```

My Control Adapter looks like

```
public class RadioButtonAdapter : WebControlAdapter {

    public new RadioButton Control => (RadioButton) base.Control;

    #region Overrides of WebControlAdapter

    protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
      base.Render(writer);
    }

    #endregion
  }
}
```

**No adapter**

Without using the control adapter my radio buttons obviously render fine.

[image]

**Adapter**

Adding my control adapter and changing nothing else, I get unexpected behavior:

[image]

I have tried adding calls to make the base control render such as

```
  RenderChildren(writer);
  RenderContents(writer);
```

but I can never seem to get the base to control to render.

Ultimately what I would like to have is something like:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{

  writer.WriteBeginTag("div");
  writer.AddAttribute("class", "wrapper");
  //Render existing control
  //Control.RenderControl();
  writer.WriteEndTag("div");

}
```

My questions is, is this even possible, if so am I doing something obviously wrong. Any suggestions or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use the ControlAdapter class instead of the WebControlAdapter, see further below.
The problem with using the WebControlAdapter is that it renders the control by calling the RenderBeginTag, RenderContents and RenderEndTag. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.adapters.webcontroladapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

However in the case of the checkbox, the RenderContents isn't what generates the contents, instead it is the Render method. And the Render method of the control is executed when using the ControlAdapter class. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.adapters.controladapter%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

```
public class RadioButtonAdapter : System.Web.UI.Adapters.ControlAdapter {
    protected override void BeginRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        writer.Write("<div class=\"wrapper\">");
        base.BeginRender(writer);
    }
    protected override void EndRender(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
        base.EndRender(writer);
        writer.Write("</div>");
    }
}
```

Comment: You nailed it. I just tested and this works fine. Thank you very much!

Comment: Glad i could be of assistance.